# how to get argument integer in callee?

Tags: c, assembly, att

I have the following code (caller.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int callee(int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  callee(4);
  return 1;
}
```

and (callee.s):

```
.globl callee

callee:
  pop %eax
  add $4, %eax
  ret
```

I compile with: 
gcc -m32 caller.c callee.s

and run:

./a.out

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I am wondering what my mistake(s) is/are as I believed that main should now push a 32 bite number of the stack. I havent changed stack so that callee should now be able to pop that number from the same stack. Maybe I should add (add $4, %esp) before the pop (if the address of callee is in the "way"/actually been popped). I have tried that too with no success. callee should now get the number from the stack and add 4 to it. The eax-register should be where the return value from callee to caller should be kept (calling convention), but here I ignore the return value.

Could someone assist me?

related question:
 [calling assembly function from c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901261/calling-assembly-function-from-c)

calling convention:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions

Comment: This fails because your `pop %eax` takes the return address pushed by the _CALL_ instruction and puts in in _EAX_. Remove the `pop %eax` and simply access the first argument via `mov 4(%esp), %eax`. After execution is transferred to a function (in 32-bit code) the return address is at 0(ESP), first argument at 4(ESP), second argument at 8(ESP) etc.

Comment: To return an int from a function, load it into `eax` (however, check the specifics of your platform/compiler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(With the x86-32 calling convention,) the arguments to a function are pushed on the stack *first*, and then the return address.  Thus, your `pop` instruction popped the *return address*, and the subsequent `ret` tried to return to address 0x00000004, which is unmapped memory, causing a crash.

Also, in this convention the callee is *not* supposed to pop its arguments.  The caller will do that.

The code you should have written is

```
callee:
    movl 4(%esp), %eax
    addl $4, %eax
    ret
```

You can confirm this for yourself by compiling

```
unsigned int callee(unsigned int x) { return x + 4; }
```

with the options `-m32 -O2 -S -fomit-frame-pointer` and inspecting the `.s` file produced; you should get the same assembly code as above.